# Primefaces Datatable scroll to page from backing bean

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2

I am working with primefaces datatable and I set the selected item from my backing bean. However, This record is in page 3; so i want to scroll to that page programmatically from my backing bean. Is there a way to do so from JAVA?

PS: I found this way to set page from Javascript but it's not exactly what i want

```
PF('WidgetVar').getPagintaor().setPage(PageNum);
```

Comment: Sure when you use 'binding' (the binding attribute on each JSF component), you can set the page via java iirc

Comment: can you please develop little more about the way to bind the page ?

Comment: Google is your friend: https://www.google.com/search?q=primefaces+datatable+binding results in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840502/binding-primefaces-datatable-with-org-primefaces-component-datatable-datatable

Comment: Or https://www.google.com/search?q=primefaces+datatable+binding+paging